# How to build the F# compiler from source

Tags: f#

After the [recent announcement that the F# compiler source was available under the apache license](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/dsyme/announcing-the-f-compiler-library-source-code-drop) I decided I'd like to have a go at building the compiler from source. However, I fell at the first post as there seems to be a missing file “Microsoft.FSharp-proto.Targets”. Is this the same “Microsoft.FSharp-proto.Targets” that is available in [“Microsoft F#, August 2010 Community Technology Preview”](https://web.archive.org/web/20101002154712/http://www.microsoft.com:80/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=F8C623AE-AEF6-4A06-A185-05F59BE47D67)? What other steps are necessary to build the compiler. Will the F# team be providing a script that “just works” to build the compiler?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I haven't run these yet (PC configuration problems?), but there's a detailed set of instructions in the source distribution at [`compiler/2.0/Nov2010/README.html`](http://fsharppowerpack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/53135#969815).

These instructions are a little different to the ones @desco wrote that relate to the previous CTP.

Comment: Wow, you're right. Don't know how I missed that. Seems to be working now.

Answer (score 3):

Not so long ago before this announcement I've written about building compiler from sources supplied with F# CTP ([F#: Building compiler from sources.](http://v2matveev.blogspot.com/2010/08/f-building-compiler-from-sources.html)). Hope nothing was changed since that time.

Comment: Unfortunately it seems the process has changed, the missing file I mentioned "Mircosoft.FSharp-proto.Targets" is not available in the F# distrib, a similarly named "fsharp-proto-build.proj" is available. Not yet sure if this is the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

I just downloaded and successfully compiled F# so I thought I'd add an update.

1. I downloaded from http://fsharppowerpack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets
2. I extracted the files and navigated to `fsharppowerpack-66272\compiler\2.0\Aug2011`
3. It contains a `readme.html` that suggests a number of ways to build.
4. With that readme I made the following script which successfully compiled F# for me.

Install NUnit first if you want to compile the unit tests.

```
set MSB40=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\
set Path=%Path%;%MSB40%
cd src
msbuild fsharp-proto-build.proj /p:TargetFramework=cli\4.0
ngen install ..\Proto\cli\4.0\bin\fsc-proto.exe
msbuild fsharp-library-build.proj /p:TargetFramework=cli\4.0
msbuild fsharp-compiler-build.proj /p:TargetFramework=cli\4.0
msbuild fsharp-library-unittests-build.proj /p:TargetFramework=cli\4.0
msbuild fsharp-compiler-unittests-build.proj /p:TargetFramework=cli\4.0
ngen install ..\Debug\cli\4.0\bin\fsi.exe
pause
```

`Note:` I already had VS2010 and the FSharpPowerPack installed.